# Active Directory Roles - developing locally

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm looking to switch this local environment to use Windows Authentication in order to facilitate the usage of the following logic inside of the code.

```
User.IsInRole("BRV_Projects_Edit");
```

I'm launching dotnet core locally in a windows environment using the command

```
"dotnet run"
```

My understanding is this will launch the Main() entry point

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>().UseIIS();
}
```

Does the UseIIS() indicate that this will launch IISExpress locally? Does this mean I should be able to locate a web.config to change the authentication scheme?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. The `dotnet CLI` cannot launch IIS Express as it is not cross platform (see [this answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/120948/the-launch-profile-iisexpress-development-could-no.html) on the Visual Studio Developer Community site. If you use `dotnet run` then it will host the app in `Kestrel`

The `UseIIS()`, `UseIISIntegration()` and `UseKestrel()` calls enable your app to be hosted in the different environments but do nothing to actually launch those hosts.

The actual host used is defined in the `launchsettings.json` file which should be part of your web application (under Properties in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer).

Also, you do not need to add `UseIIS()` yourself as it is done for you as part of the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()` call. You can read more about what `CreateDefaultBuilder()` does [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

There is another [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122376/invoking-iisexpress-using-command-line-to-host-asp-net-core-app) that will help you launch IIS Express from the command line for `dotnet` apps.

If you want to host the app in `IIS` then the [instructions are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Your cross platform statement clarified my perspective. By using Visual Studio 2017 as apposed to Visual Studio Code I am able to easily launch iisexpress.